# How to sync Podcast playing across devices (iPhone, iPad, Mac)?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, monterey

I've got an iPhone 11 running the latest iOS (15.1)

I've also got a MacBook Pro running Monterrey (12.0.1)

How can I sync Apple Podcasts across devices? I'd like to be able to listen on either device, and have the other know where I left off

Is this possible?

I've followed the directions here: https://support.apple.com/guide/podcasts/listen-to-podcasts-on-all-your-devices-pod5c911347/mac

Yet the library and current playback don't seem to follow that setting

Continuity doesn't seem to work for me, either (bringing my iPhone alongside my MPB and starting Podcasts from the iPhone-badged icon in my Dock)

Comment: Interestingly (or, annoyingly) .. this still happens on iOS 17 [beta] and macOS 13.4.1 :|

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to use Continuity. Bring the phone close to the Mac and an icon shows up in the Dock signifying you can launch Podcasts from your phone. That will take you to the correct position.

Going the other way is possible too. Bring your phone close to the Mac and swipe up to get into multitasking card mode on the phone. You will see a bar at the bottom with the Podcasts app from the Mac which should take you to the proper place.

I don't have a workaround if you use the Apple TV to listen to Podcasts.

Comment: I've tried that - and while the Podcasts-on-iPhone icon will appear, it hasn't allowed me to sync [yet]. I get the error "you're not following this podcast" popup